# Mobile traffic of my second site redirected to my base site [Edited,have a look]

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I have a strange issue with my website and it seems i am unable to understand what cauese the problem.I would highly appreciate your help.The Scenario is

I have two websites.

1. Website A
2. Website B

Website A is simply hosted within the **root directory** of my hosting account.Within this **root** **directory** i have a sub folder " **subfolder A** " and within which is another subfolder " **subfolder B** " that contains my site **Website B**

so the path looks like

root/sublfolder_A/subfolder_B/

that contains my **Website B ( i.e subfolder_B) **

All goes fine.When i access the website B from my desktop/Laptop Website B is loaded normally.

**but when i access the Website through a mobile device , mobile site of Website A is loaded while as it should load website_B**

Also , to let you know , both websites have different URL's and not subdomain's or anything.

What could be the problem ? 
htaccess of website B or website A ? or something else ?

Here is the htaccess of my website B

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule .* index.php [F] 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without more info (such as if you're using a CMS platform, redirect scripts/modules, etc...), but it sounds like your server is redirecting your mobile browser user-agent from website B to website A, so I'd look at .htaccess in website B and your server config file. Also be sure to clear your mobile browser's cache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dan 
I am using Joomla for Both my sites.

Here is the .htaccess of my second website

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Comment: It's probably better to edit this in in your question. It makes it a lot more readable.

Comment: This question is very specific to your setup.   Other people are unlikely to have similar enough setups for this to be helpful to them.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't properly configured your web server. Since you've mentioned .htaccess files I'm going to assume that you're using Apache web server. Depending on your OS the layout of your web server configuration will vary. If you're using a Redhat variant or Windows then your configuration will all probably be in one file. If you are using a Debian variant then you likely have a site-available and sites-enabled directory with each site in separate files. Figure out how yours are laid out and look for the VirtualHost configurations. In the configurations which use files in site-available this will go in 2 separate files and in the more standard installations this will all be near the end of httpd.conf. Here is a sample configuration script which does what you are trying to do:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

I would put these two sites in the same directory as they have done in the sample. If the content of the two sites are the same then I wouldn't use separate DNS names. Just use separate virtual host name. So name the sites: `www.yoursite.com` and `mobile.yoursite.com`.

Once that is setup you'll probably want to redirect to the mobile site automatically when someone visits with a mobile device. This is a long topic in itself so I'll leave that as further reading.

http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/detecting-and-redirecting-mobile-users/
OR Google https://www.google.com/search?q=automatic+redirect+mobile+devices

Comment: and i dont have access to my http.conf file.

Also , the sites are different that why i have put them in different folder's.

Comment: As your links mention about redirecting to a mobile site.I dont want to redirect.My problem is that Website B is redirected when accessed through a mobile to the mobile site of Website A which i dont want.i want the website B to b loaded when it is requested for website B not Website A.

Regards :)